# Authorize.net - SIM - How to integrate without exposing API login ID

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, authorize.net

I am integrating an Authorize.Net SIM API using ColdFusion...

In the example template, the form exposes the APILogin and the Fingerprint which effectively is contrary to directions in the API documentation...

Does anyone have suggestions on how to accomplish this without exposing these form values?

```
<FORM method='post' action='#posturl#' >
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_login' value='#loginID#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_amount' value='#amount#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_description' value='#description#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_invoice_num' value='#invoice#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value='#sequence#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value='#timestamp4#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value='#fingerprint#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_test_request' value='#testMode#' />
    <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
    <input type='submit' value='#label#' />
</FORM>
```

Comment: no no.. you are right Ken, don't want to expose your figureprint let alone your login ID,. Keep these on the server (an application variable or a DB table) but never put them in a hidden field. @cfqueryaparams solution is more what you want - though you may need a bit of debugging.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - Ignoring the server side option for a moment, why would the fingerprint need to be kept secret? Their docs say it is just a hash of various fields, and does not stay the same. I am not sure about the API login. Their docs are conflicting, though they do make a distinction between the API login and user login.

Comment: @rhldr - If that is the case, you should post your comment as an answer. So it is more visible to those searching the archives.

Comment: You might be right about the fingerprint - it's a sort of timestamp thing (various fields + time) I believe. but the overall idea is to avoid exposing data that the user doesn't "own" but is specific to the site owner.

Comment: Agreed, but it does seem strange that their examples direct developers to embed a "login" value in a client `<form>` if it should be kept secret :) I do not whether it is correct or not, just that it does not seem like API will work without doing so, and again it is not the same as the user login. That makes me wonder if the part about keeping it secret is an error in their documentation.

Comment: @Leigh - My sense is, all the data you need to maliciously post a charge is contained in those fields, even if you do it within the 15 minute window... Now, whether or not you have anything to gain from that, can only be determined by the bad guys...

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfhttp url="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="POST" result="fpResult">
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="x_login" value="#loginID#" />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="x_amount" value="#amount#" />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_description' value='#description#' />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_invoice_num' value='#invoice#' />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_fp_sequence' value='#sequence#' />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_fp_timestamp' value='#timestamp#' />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_fp_hash' value='#fingerprint#' />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_test_request' value='#testMode#' />
  <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
  <input type="submit" default="submit" />
  ...
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#fpResult#">
```

CFDumping the result, as I have, is a great tool for understanding the structure.

Answer (score 0):

oK, This seems to solve my issue... Effectively I hide the Fields using

```
<cfif IsDefined("form.submit")>
```

Once the Submit is Clicked, the forms variables are visible for a brief period, I use JS to submit the form variables to Authorize.net..

although it seems to solve my problem, I noticed the variables are visible on the Hosted Payment form... Which is also conflicts with their rules...

Any thoughts?

```
<cfif IsDefined("form.submit")>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {



    window.document.forms[0].submit();
  });
</script>
</cfif>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<cfif NOT IsDefined("form.submit")>
<cfset posturl="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#">
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined("form.submit")>
<cfset posturl="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">
</cfif>



<FORM method='post' action='#posturl#' >
    <cfif IsDefined("form.submit")> 
            <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_login' value='#loginID#' />
            <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value='#sequence#' />
            <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value='#timestamp#' />
            <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value='#fingerprint#' />
            <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_test_request' value='#testMode#' />
            <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_method' value='CC' />
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Ken - That really does not "solve" the problem. As you say, the information is still visible. Not to mention javascript can be easily disabled. There is no way to hide values from the browser when you are using client side code ie html/javascript/etcetera. By definition, those *must* be visible for the browser interpret the code. Though it does sounds like their docs contains contradictory information, perhaps some of it is outdated. (cont'd)

Comment: For example, the "fingerprint" is just a hash of varying values, that does not stay the same. So I am not sure why it should be considered secret. Also, they mention there is a difference between API login and user login. Unfortunately, it does not sound like you can use the server side POST option @cfqueryparam suggested, since it is a hosted payment form. Personally, I would suggesting going straight to the source. Ask Authorize.net about this.

Comment: Leigh - Thanks for your reply.. I understand your points and agree with you.. I have talked with Authorize.Net, and they were less than helpful and even found it dificult to explain the problem to them... Effectively, they ended simply saying  "Kenny, we're not the developer, you are.." basically, was a difficult and frustrating discussion..

Comment: Ugh .. sorry to hear that. I have not dealt with them personally, but have had similar experiences with other companies. Some companies seem trained to automatically reject all inquires with a canned "You are asking us to code for you. That is not our job" response. Even when that is clearly not the case. Sometimes you have to dumb it down for them. Tell them "I am using {Example X}. It works. However, it exposes the API login to the client which violates your own recommendations in {link Y} - which says *'..do not expose the API login to anyone'*. Which of them is correct?"

Comment: @KenMais Look into the AIM (Advanced--Integration Method) vs the SIM (Server--). I did this years ago (wish I still had the code to give you some insight). Authorize.net's API wasn't too bad to work with 10 years ago. I recall being able to hide my credentials using things like the server-side form post I suggested.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Yes, there are definitely different options. One difference between AIM and SIM seems to be where the payment form is hosted. Some people choose SIM because the do not want to/or are not equipped to handle hosting that side of things. So the best option all depends. Side note, a user named "rhldr" (who seemed to be affiliated with authorize.net) posted a comment earlier that said the login did not need to be kept secret, only the transaction key. However, he later deleted the comment for some reason ...

Comment: @KenMais The API Login is not considered sensitive.  When using SIM, you calculate the fingerprint using the formula found in the documentation and send it along with the API Login.  The fingerprint is only valid for 15 minutes. Authorize.Net will display the hosted payment form using the amount you included in the fingerprint.

Comment: @rhldr - It exposes sensitive data even if it's valid for 15 minutes.. In my mind, this creates a security risk.. Maybe I'm new at this, but the documentation is very clear... the API Login/password must be stored securely.. That seems to mean, dont present in a way that is readily available to the the bad guys...